# Paypal not picking up shipping?

Tags: html, forms, paypal

this is strange, for some reason this paypal isn't picking up my shipping_1 value, yet I have done another form similar, and it goes through ok? I have no idea what's wrong with it..

```
<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" name="cart" id="cart" onSubmit="return checkform(this);">
  <div class="shopContainer">
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="coursesTable">
      <tr>
        <td width="150" height="18" align="left" valign="middle"><strong>First Name: *</strong></td>
        <td width="200" height="18" align="left" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" class="input" /></td>
        <td rowspan="8" align="left" valign="top"><div id="paymentInfo">
            <p><strong>*</strong> Required Fields</p>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="150" height="18" align="left" valign="middle"><strong>Last Name: *</strong></td>
        <td width="200" height="18" align="left" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="last_name" id="last_name" class="input" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="150" height="18" align="left" valign="middle"><strong>Your Email: *</strong></td>
        <td width="200" height="18" align="left" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="input" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="150" height="18" align="left" valign="middle"><strong>Street Address: *</strong></td>
        <td width="200" height="18" align="left" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="address1" id="address1" class="input" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" height="18" valign="middle"><strong>City: *</strong></td>
        <td align="left" height="18" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="input" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="150" height="18" align="left" valign="middle"><strong>State: *</strong></td>
        <td width="200" height="18" align="left" valign="middle"><div id="entry_state1">
            <select name="state" id="state" class="input">
              <option value="" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
            </select>
          </div></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="150" height="18" align="left" valign="middle"><strong>Postcode: *</strong></td>
        <td width="200" height="18" align="left" valign="middle"><input type="text" name="zip" id="zip" class="postcode" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="150" height="18" align="left" valign="middle"><strong>Country: *</strong></td>
        <td width="200" height="18" align="left" valign="middle"><select name="country" id="country" onChange="javascript: loadstate1();" class="selectstate">
            <option value="">Please Select</option>
            <option value="AL">Albania</option>
            <option value="DZ">Algeria</option>
            <option value="AS">American Samoa</option>
            <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
            <option value="AI">Anguilla</option>
            <option value="AG">Antigua And Barbuda</option>
            <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
            <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
            <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
            <option value="AU" SELECTED> Australia</option>
            <option value="AT">Austria</option>
            <option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
            <option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
            <option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
            <option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
            <option value="BB">Barbados</option>
            <option value="BY">Belarus</option>
            <option value="BE">Belgium</option>
            <option value="BZ">Belize</option>
            <option value="BJ">Benin</option>
            <option value="BM">Bermuda</option>
            <option value="BO">Bolivia</option>
            <option value="BA">Bosnia And Herzegovina</option>
            <option value="BW">Botswana</option>
            <option value="BR">Brazil</option>
            <option value="VG">British Virgin Islands</option>
            <option value="BN">Brunei</option>
            <option value="BG">Bulgaria</option>
            <option value="BF">Burkina Faso</option>
            <option value="KH">Cambodia</option>
            <option value="CM">Cameroon</option>
            <option value="CA">Canada</option>
            <option value="CV">Cape Verde</option>
            <option value="KY">Cayman Islands</option>
            <option value="CL">Chile</option>
            <option value="CN">China</option>
            <option value="CO">Colombia</option>
            <option value="CK">Cook Islands</option>
            <option value="HR">Croatia</option>
            <option value="CY">Cyprus</option>
            <option value="CZ">Czech Republic</option>
            <option value="DK">Denmark</option>
            <option value="DJ">Djibouti</option>
            <option value="DM">Dominica</option>
            <option value="DO">Dominican Republic</option>
            <option value="TP">East Timor</option>
            <option value="EG">Egypt</option>
            <option value="SV">El Salvador</option>
            <option value="EE">Estonia</option>
            <option value="FJ">Fiji</option>
            <option value="FI">Finland</option>
            <option value="FR">France</option>
            <option value="GF">French Guiana</option>
            <option value="PF">French Polynesia</option>
            <option value="GA">Gabon</option>
            <option value="GE">Georgia</option>
            <option value="DE">Germany</option>
            <option value="GH">Ghana</option>
            <option value="GI">Gibraltar</option>
            <option value="GR">Greece</option>
            <option value="GD">Grenada</option>
            <option value="GP">Guadeloupe</option>
            <option value="GU">Guam</option>
            <option value="GT">Guatemala</option>
            <option value="GN">Guinea</option>
            <option value="GY">Guyana</option>
            <option value="HT">Haiti</option>
            <option value="HN">Honduras</option>
            <option value="HK">Hong Kong</option>
            <option value="HU">Hungary</option>
            <option value="IS">Iceland</option>
            <option value="IN">India</option>
            <option value="ID">Indonesia</option>
            <option value="IE">Ireland</option>
            <option value="IL">Israel</option>
            <option value="IT">Italy</option>
            <option value="CI">Ivory Coast</option>
            <option value="JM">Jamaica</option>
            <option value="JP">Japan</option>
            <option value="JO">Jordan</option>
            <option value="KZ">Kazakhstan</option>
            <option value="KE">Kenya</option>
            <option value="KW">Kuwait</option>
            <option value="LA">Lao People's Democratic Republic</option>
            <option value="LV">Latvia</option>
            <option value="LB">Lebanon</option>
            <option value="LS">Lesotho</option>
            <option value="LT">Lithuania</option>
            <option value="LU">Luxembourg</option>
            <option value="MO">Macao</option>
            <option value="MK">Macedonia</option>
            <option value="MG">Madagascar</option>
            <option value="MY">Malaysia</option>
            <option value="MV">Maldives</option>
            <option value="ML">Mali</option>
            <option value="MT">Malta</option>
            <option value="MH">Marshall Islands</option>
            <option value="MQ">Martinique</option>
            <option value="MU">Mauritius</option>
            <option value="MX">Mexico</option>
            <option value="FM">Micronesia, Federated States Of</option>
            <option value="MD">Moldova</option>
            <option value="MN">Mongolia</option>
            <option value="MS">Montserrat</option>
            <option value="MA">Morocco</option>
            <option value="MZ">Mozambique</option>
            <option value="NA">Namibia</option>
            <option value="NP">Nepal</option>
            <option value="NL">Netherlands</option>
            <option value="AN">Netherlands Antilles</option>
            <option value="NZ">New Zealand</option>
            <option value="NI">Nicaragua</option>
            <option value="MP">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
            <option value="NO">Norway</option>
            <option value="OM">Oman</option>
            <option value="PK">Pakistan</option>
            <option value="PW">Palau</option>
            <option value="PS">Palestine</option>
            <option value="PA">Panama</option>
            <option value="PG">Papua New Guinea</option>
            <option value="PY">Paraguay</option>
            <option value="PE">Peru</option>
            <option value="PH">Philippines, Republic Of</option>
            <option value="PL">Poland</option>
            <option value="PT">Portugal</option>
            <option value="PR">Puerto Rico</option>
            <option value="QA">Qatar</option>
            <option value="RO">Romania</option>
            <option value="RU">Russian Federation</option>
            <option value="RW">Rwanda</option>
            <option value="KN">Saint Kitts And Nevis</option>
            <option value="LC">Saint Lucia</option>
            <option value="VC">Saint Vincent And The Grendines</option>
            <option value="WS">Samoa</option>
            <option value="SA">Saudi Arabia</option>
            <option value="CS">Serbia And Montenegro</option>
            <option value="SC">Seychelles</option>
            <option value="SG">Singapore</option>
            <option value="SK">Slovakia</option>
            <option value="SI">Slovenia</option>
            <option value="SB">Solomon Islands</option>
            <option value="ZA">South Africa</option>
            <option value="KR">South Korea</option>
            <option value="ES">Spain</option>
            <option value="LK">Sri Lanka</option>
            <option value="SE">Sweden</option>
            <option value="CH">Switzerland</option>
            <option value="SZ">Switzerland</option>
            <option value="TW">Taiwan</option>
            <option value="TZ">Tanzania, United Republic Of</option>
            <option value="TH">Thailand</option>
            <option value="TG">Togo</option>
            <option value="TO">Tonga</option>
            <option value="TT">Trinidad And Tobago</option>
            <option value="TN">Tunisia</option>
            <option value="TR">Turkey</option>
            <option value="TM">Turkmenistan</option>
            <option value="TC">Turks And Caicos Islands</option>
            <option value="UG">Uganda</option>
            <option value="UA">Ukraine</option>
            <option value="AE">United Arab Emirates</option>
            <option value="GB">United Kingdom</option>
            <option value="US">United States Of America</option>
            <option value="UY">Uruguay</option>
            <option value="UZ">Uzbekistan</option>
            <option value="VU">Vanuatu</option>
            <option value="VE">Venezuela</option>
            <option value="VN">Vietnam</option>
            <option value="VI">Virgin Islands, U.s.</option>
            <option value="YE">Yemen Arab Republic</option>
            <option value="ZM">Zambia</option>
          </select></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" style="border: solid 1px #e2d5b4; margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;" class="coursesTable">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th align="left" valign="bottom" style="border-right: solid 1px #e2d5b4; background: #e2d5b4;">ITEMS</th>
          <th align="left" valign="bottom" width="50" style="border-right: solid 1px #e2d5b4; background: #e2d5b4;">CODE</th>
          <th align="left" valign="bottom" width="50" style="border-right: solid 1px #e2d5b4; background: #e2d5b4;">PRICE</th>
          <th align="left" valign="bottom" width="20" style="background: #e2d5b4;">QTY</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tr onMouseOver="this.bgColor='#fbeccc';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='';">
        <td align="left" valign="middle" height="20" style="border-right: solid 1px #e2d5b4;"><strong>Books:</strong> A Healing Initiation - Recognise the Healer Within
          <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" id="item_name_1" value="A Healing Initiation - Recognise the Healer Within" /></td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle" height="20" style="border-right: solid 1px #e2d5b4;"> 01-02
          <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" id="item_number_1" value="01-02"></td>
        <td align="left" valign="middle" height="20" style="border-right: solid 1px #e2d5b4;"> $24.95
          <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" id="amount_1" value="24.95"></td>
        <td align="center" valign="middle" height="20"> 1
          <input type="hidden" name="quantity_1" id="quantity_1" value="1">
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="right" valign="middle" style="border-top: solid 1px #e2d5b4;"><table width="320" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="coursesTable">
            <tr>
              <td width="30" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox" name="agree"></td>
              <td align="right" valign="middle">I have read and agree to the <a href="/index.php?option=com_shop&view=terms&Itemid=8">Terms &amp; Conditions</a>.</td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="4" align="right" valign="middle"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="coursesTable">
            <tr>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><strong>POSTAGE:</strong></td>
              <td align="right" valign="middle">$7.95 <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" id="shipping_1" value="7.95"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><strong>SUBTOTAL:</strong></td>
              <td align="right" valign="middle"><div style="text-align: right;">$24.95</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" valign="middle"><strong>TOTAL:</strong></td>
              <td align="right" valign="middle"><div style="text-align: right;"><strong>$32.90</strong></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td align="left" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
              <td align="right" valign="middle" style="text-align: right;"><p align="right"><a href="#" onclick="if (checkform(cart)) document['cart'].submit();">Checkout</a></p></td>
            </tr>
          </table></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="my@emailaddresshere.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD" />
  </div>
</form>
```

I can't seem to find what's wrong.. I checked it with my other form (which does work, but on a different website) and the shipping_1 field is identical - with different values of course :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using

```
<input type="hidden" name="handling_cart" value="[your shipping cost]" />
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that was it.. still not sure why shipping_1 would all of a sudden stop working?? Anyway, thank you again :)

Comment: yeah paypal is weird. i don't know why they don't just clean up their antiquated system and do something more flexible like GCO. oh well. glad i could help!

Comment: I'm with n8wrl - they have a ton of documentation (which is rare), but sorting through it is a nightmare. This worked perfectly. StackOverflow to the rescue again!